# columns with year between two dates

Tags: python, date, matrix

I would like to create a dataframe with the years between to dates.

[START    END](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIkL2.png)

the final data frame would be like that.

[final data Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92CK5.png)

Many thanks

Comment: Please [do not post images of data](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), add the information as text (within code fences etc.) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example data:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Start date": [2022, 2021, 2021, 2022],
    "Maturity": [2023, 2022, 2025, 2028],
})
```

**Solution:**

```
start = df["star"].min()
end = df["end"].max()

for year in range(start, end+1):
    df[year] = np.where((df["start"] <= year) & (df["end"] >= year), year, np.nan)
```

**Output:**[image]

Comment: You don't need `np.where` here. Just do `df.loc[(df["Start date"] <= year) & (year <= df["Maturity"]), year] = year`.